# Orbeon Forms, Form Runner and Form Builder don't work in IE11

Tags: orbeon, internet-explorer-11

Having problems with using Orbeon Forms in IE11.
Tested Orbeon version 3.9PE and 4.2PE

In Orbeon 4.2 Form Builder it's not possible to create a form. On the initial form metadata submit appears

**Exception in client-side code.•Message: Unable to get property 'nextSibling' of undefined or null reference**

In Bookshelf sample form **Clear**, **Save** and **Review** buttons don't function.

In Orbeon 3.9 tested Xforms Sandbox - pushing the buttons doesn't give any result.

And in handmade forms also the same problem.

Under developer tool network tab it's seen that browser communicates with the server, but the browser doesn't show any response to the user. No exceptions are seen in the console also.

Is this an Orbeon or a browser problem?

Answer (score 0):

This has now been [fixed](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1461). The fix will be in Orbeon Forms 4.5, and generally things should work with IE11 with Orbeon Forms 4.5.